# toolkit:timepicker Windows Phone 7 app set interval minutes

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, timepicker

In silverlight there is an option called PopupMinutesInterval to set the minutes interval in the timepicker page. Is there an option for Windows phone 7 app in Xaml?

```
<toolkit:TimePicker PopupMinutesInterval="15" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually got the solution, I used a TimeSpanPicker.

Comment: Yes, with this code `<coding:TimeSpanPicker Step="00:15" />` for namespace `xmlns:coding="clr-namespace:Coding4Fun.Toolkit.Controls;assembly=Coding4Fun.Toolkit.Controls"`